# Visual studio 2008/2010 dilemma

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

We have a project which is being developed by a 3rd party. They are using LINQ and .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008.  We are currently at 2005 with .NET 2.  Once they have delivered the code to us, we are unsure as to whether we will be able to compile/build their code using our current Visual Studio toolkit.  I know we can download .NET 3.5, but unsure as to whether we will have problems with Visual Studio.

So we are considering to upgrade. But since Visual Studio 2010 is soon to be released do we wait for that or upgrade to 2008?

Comment: Sure you grab 2010. Just one month of waiting left.

Comment: Grab the release candidate of VS2010... it's almost perfect, and definitely good enough to use in production

Answer (score 3):

Here's a plan:

1. Upgrade to RC now for non-critical
   items. Gain familiarity with it.
2. Test your 3rd party app in RC to
   identify any issues.
3. **Add an addendum to your contract
   with the 3rd party** that they will
   need to deliver the app in .NET 4.0 RTM,
   compatible with VS2010 RTM, i.e. get
   them to upgrade too!

Comment: +1 on the contract addendum.  Some vendors will provide this only if it is explicitly requested.  Moreover, it shows that you are looking closely not only at the finished product but also at the code that will be delivered.  It is important to keep the vendors on their toes and focused on producing high-quality deliverables.

Comment: Spoken like a true MS sales rep ;-)  [Sorry couldn't resist. Effectively your advice is quite sensible, and my comment means no offense; but the bit about propagating the "virus" seemed funny, is all]

Comment: Which edition is best?
# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
# Visual Studio 2010 Premium
# Visual Studio 2010 Professional
Can this be installed alongside Visual Studio 2005 or are we best 'sandboxing' this on a separate VM/Box.

Comment: @jon: that's really hard to say objectively, it really depends on your needs. here's a comparison list of the different versions: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products. VS2010 will release on April 12.

Comment: Ok thanks Otaku you are a great help! We are currently on Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition, so I don't know how that relates to Visual Studio 2010.  I need to balance trying out cool features on the release candidate with what we will realistically be able to purchase.

Comment: not entirely sure of all the details. i recommend you chat with a microsoft pre-sale rep. have your questions ready in advance. you can click the "chat with a representative" link on this site: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/buy and i'm sure they'll try to help you with all of these details.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to 2010. We talk of a month here until you get your hands off. AND it being in RC status (so you can actually test now that it compiles etc- no major changes coming). note that I don say go .NET 4.0 NOW - just use VS 2010. No sense in moving to 2008 at this point in time at all.

Comment: I agrees - you can use 2010 and target your 2005/2.0 projects - I think you have to convert the csproj files, but it's not as if you're deleting them. The 2010 IDE is very nice, there's lot to enjoy there ...

Answer (score 1):

With the release being so close I would wait for the upgrade and use the release candidate until then.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a no brainer.  Unless you have immediate operational needs, you can wait for VS2010 and/or better yet, install and use the release candidate (in a non-critical workstation / role) and get acquainted with the new stuff.